# how do i send a rest call of a large json using ruby

Tags: ruby, json, rest

I want to send a http request of a json containg a file(say 100 mb) that has been encrypted and compressed.

sample
`{data: some_100_mb_file, name: some_name, iv: some_iv}`

to some url:
`http://localhost:3000/journal_content/enc_data`

Comment: @UriAgassi the blog only tells about streaming response. i need to send large request

Answer (score 0):

Use restclient gem.

```
RestClient.post http://localhost:3000/journal_content/enc_data {data: some_100_mb_file, name: some_name, iv: some_iv}
```

Comment: i get error `block in build_stream': failed to allocate memory (NoMemoryError)`

Comment: I can tell with confidence that you have not big RAM on PC.

Comment: OK.
What DB?- If Oracle do following steps:
1) Download old MySQL client library
2) Copy the lib file in ruby folder (I have following path C:\\Ruby\\bin)
3) Restart you MySQL

Comment: Or increase the memory limit under "Server"->"Rails" tab.